# State monocity of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Let f(x) be a derivable function defined over the set of real numbers such that

$$f(f(x))=k(x^7+2x),$$ $k$ is not equal to zero. Then we have to prove $f(x)$ is either increasing or decreasing .

I am not getting any try. Can anybody help me here.

Comment: Differentiate f, what do you obtain?

Comment: Is $f(f(x))=k(x^7+2x)$ or $f(x)=k(x^7+2x)$?

Comment: try to take derivative of this equation using the chain rule. What can you say about points where the derivative is zero?

Comment: @stud_iisc the first one is correct

Comment: @RyArazi I could not understandf how

Comment: the chain rule gives you:
$f'(x) \cdot f'(f(x)) = k(7x^6+2)$.

what happens when f'(x) =0? is there a solution?

Comment: @RyArazi no there is no solution

Comment: And what happens if for some $x_1,x_2$ you will find $f(x_1)>0, f(x_2)<0$? What Darboux's theorem says in this case?

Comment: @RyArazi when that happens it means k=0 or $f'(f(x))=infinity$

Comment: @laflaca after that

Comment: you wrote that $k\ne0$ in your question. Also $f$ is derivable and that means $f'(y)\in \mathbb{R}$ for every real $y$ (and for $f(x)$). So what does it means?

Comment: @RyArazi that means it can be increasing or decreasing . But it cannot be constant . Am I correct

Comment: it means more than that - it means that $f'$ can't change it's sign because in each change it will must go through a point in which $f'(x)=0$!